# Ubuntu Server 16.04: Sees only logical volumes (hardware RAID), doesn't see physical disks

Tags: 16.04, server, system-installation, raid, disk

### Situation:

I have a server *(see info below)*. I need to install Ubuntu on the physical drive, but not on the logical one (hardware RAID). But during installation I can't see my physical drives, so it's impossible right now.

### Problem:

I don't need to create RAID volume for installing Ubuntu. I just want to install it on the physical drive. I've already tried disabling RAID controller using BIOS, but it doesn't work.

This is how I disabled RAID controller:

[image]
[image]

### Server Characteristics:

Model: `HP ProLiant DL580 G7`
RAID Controller: `HP ProLiant DL580 G7`
Operating system: `Ubuntu Desktop 16.04.4`
OS Architecture: `64-bit (AMD64)`

Thanks for help

Comment: how did you try disabling RAID mode?

Comment: @SebastianStark I disabled it in BIOS _(see photos above)_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you would configure a controller with JBOD mode to do what you want. Your controller does not seem to support this. Instead you could configure a RAID0 set for each physical disk, it will have the same effect. Technically you would still not see the physical disk in the OS, but the corresponding number of RAID0 set. Still you would have the minimum possible interference of the RAID controller with your disks.

Comment: After I created logical drives from each physical drive, Ubuntu can see them now.